404 requested entity not found GET urlNotifications/metadata
I am trying to index job through the google indexing api
when I hit this api
POST https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish 

with body :
{
    "url": "https://kunfirm.me/jobs/Abia/Aba/66de5c3d8559681b41aadaf5/view",
    "type": "URL_UPDATED"
}

I get this response
{
  urlNotificationMetadata: {
    url: 'https://kunfirm.me/jobs/Abia/Aba/66de5c3d8559681b41aadaf5/view'
  }
}

but when I try to get update about this url to check if I successfully submitted this url through this api
GET https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications/metadata?url=https%3A%2F%2Fkunfirm.me%2Fjobs%2FAbia%2FAba%2F66de5c3d8559681b41aadaf5%2Fview

with the same access token I get this error
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
        "status": "NOT_FOUND"
    }
}

The links are accessible I've checked through the google search-console https://i.sstatic.net/KPYUe2kG.png
I've tried different Urls I always get the same response. I've tried to add additional scopes like https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly while generating access token, but still getting the same error. I've gone through the docs and followed each step carefully. The user has owner permission.
